# CreateView error NOT NULL constraint failed: members_experience.CustomUser_id

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

Hi i have a CustomUser model, a user can have one to many Experinces. The thing is that i want to use the CreateView on Experience and get the instance of CustomUser. When i try to post the form i get a error message NOT NULL constraint failed: members_experience.CustomUser_id.

I can solve this whit a InlineFormSet but that is not what i want in this case. Im new to Django, any tips?

thx

> **Model**

**Table 1**
*CustomUser:*

```
Class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
        email = models.EmailField(_('Epost'), unique=True,)
        personal_Id = models.CharField(_('Personnummer'),max_length=12, blank=False)
        first_name = models.CharField(_('Förnam'), max_length=30, blank=True)
        middle_name = models.CharField('Mellannamn', max_length=30, blank=True)
        last_name = models.CharField(_('Efternamn'), max_length=30, blank=True)
```

**table 2**
*Experience*

```
class Experience(models.Model):
    CustomUser = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(_('Beskrivning'), max_length=200)
    job_type = models.CharField(_('Arbetsform'), max_length=10, choices=JOB_TYPES)
    porfession = models.CharField(_('Yrke'), max_length=10, choices=PROFESSION_LIST)
    posted_on = models.DateTimeField(_('Registrerad'), auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(_('Senast uppdaterad'), auto_now=True)
    years_of_exp = models.CharField(_('Erfarenhet'), max_length=20, choices=YEARS_OF_EXP, null=True, blank=True)
```

> **URL**

```
path('<int:pk>/experienceadd/', views.ExperienceCreate.as_view(), name='ExperienceCreate'),
```

> **View**

```
class ExperienceCreate(CreateView):
    model = Experience
    template_name = 'members/experience_create_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('MemberIndex')
    fields = ['title', 'job_type', 'porfession', 'years_of_exp']
```

> **Template**

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ExperienceCreate(CreateView):
    model = Experience
    template_name = 'members/experience_create_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('MemberIndex')
    fields = ['title', 'job_type', 'porfession', 'years_of_exp']

def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.CustomUser = self.request.user
        return super(ExperienceCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

as the customuser field is a ForeignKey and you havent provided null=True, Django needs a ForeignKey ID to be populated.

Comment: I am a administrator and whant to update the experince of a specific user. The code you provided adds experice to my own user profile.

Comment: then use ORM to get that User and just add the ID to the form instance

Comment: Thank you, do you have any examples. Im totaly new to Django i know maybe this is simple for you =) thx

Answer (score 1):

In response to ur last comment on Exprator answer
Can't comment yet so I answered it here

If you want to add experience for any specific user ,add CustomUser to your createview form fields

```
  fields = ['CustomUser','title', 'job_type', 'porfession', 'years_of_exp']
```

This way you get a select option field to select the user you want

Comment: Yes that i know, the thing is that i can solve this problem with the inline formset i django. But i want the PK of the CustomUser table to be the instance of the Experience table. So that i don’t have to chose by dropdown list what user i want to add a experiences to. And be able to add Experience via a listview of CustomUsers. Thanks for the reply anyhow